# show all validator messages in html5

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm trying to show all error messages onsumbit at once.

Html5 browsers show only the first invalid element. I need to show all invalid elements at once.

It is possible?

[There an example](http://jsfiddle.net/RBbR3/)

Answer (score -1):

For java have a look at: http://about.validator.nu **Sample Apps** like HTML2HTML (nu.validator.htmlparser.tools) in *Release 1.4 2012-06-05*: http://about.validator.nu/htmlparser/htmlparser-1.4.zip

`$ java -cp PATH/TO/LIB/htmlparser-1.4.jar nu.validator.htmlparser.tools.HTML2HTML html/html_test.html out_html-test_HTML2HTML.html`

shows a list like this:

```
Warning:
Obsolete doctype. Expected “”.
File: Unknown
Line: 1 Col: 50

Error:
End tag “li” seen, but there were open elements.
File: Unknown
Line: 15 Col: 50

Error:
Unclosed element “a”.
File: Unknown
Line: 15 Col: 22
```